# Драйверы баз данных.

Tags: php, sql

Изучаю CodeIgniter, для некоторых его возможностей нужно подключать драйвер базы данных. В каком смысле драйвер? Для чего он нужен? Желательно, скиньте какую - нибудь развёрнутую статью по этой теме.

Comment: Драйвер базы данных - это просто прослойка между Вашим кодом и базой данных. Она нужна по одной простой причине - все движки баз данных достаточно разные и пришлось бы для каждой базы делать свой набор классов и свою документацию. Правильно написанный драйвер базы данных позволяет заменять базы данных и не трогать весь остальной код. Конечно, это достигается некоторым ограничением возможностей.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну вот например есть класс PDO для работы с разными БД. И чтобы была возможность работать с разными базами данных, нужно установить [драйвер](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.drivers.php) для каждой БД, с которой вы хотите работать. Это по сути то же самое, что и установить драйвера на компьютер, чтобы работать с принтером, сканером и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Драйвер нужен, чтобы подключиться в серверу БД, передать запрос и получить ответ.

Comment: То есть, это просто файл с функциями для подключения и отправки запросов?

Comment: Я бы сказал программа.

Comment: это может быть как и просто один файлик с кодом, так и целая инфраструктура с нескольких программ. В этом то и прелесть драйвера.